# Readr:read_csv has issues with specific datetimes

Tags: r, datetime, readr

I recently found the Chicago crime data website that offers CSV export. Upon importing the 6.2M+ record with readr, I noticed that all Date records with time between 12:00:00 PM and 12:59:59 PM could not be read.

I used the following to import:

```
chicagocrime = read_csv("~/R/chicago_Crime/Crimes_-_2001_to_present 20161203.csv", 
                         col_types = cols(
                              Date = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"), 
                              Location = col_skip(), 
                              `Updated On` = col_skip(), 
                              `X Coordinate` = col_skip(), 
                              `Y Coordinate` = col_skip()
                                        )
                         )
```

problems() showed the following:

```
problems(chicagocrime)
# A tibble: 156 × 4
     row   col   expected                 actual
                            
1     12  Date valid date 06/13/2005 12:40:00 PM
2     20  Date valid date 04/06/2005 12:30:00 PM
3     24  Date valid date 06/13/2005 12:45:00 PM
4     32  Date valid date 06/12/2005 12:00:00 PM
5     43  Date valid date 06/03/2005 12:00:00 PM
6     53  Date valid date 03/20/2005 12:00:00 PM
7     61  Date valid date 06/15/2005 12:33:00 PM
8     80  Date valid date 06/13/2005 12:30:00 PM
9    104  Date valid date 06/13/2005 12:46:17 PM
10   143  Date valid date 06/12/2005 12:12:30 PM
```

All other times import without issues.

The input file has the field Date in this format: "04/06/2005 12:30:00 PM". Any help or comments? (R 3.3.2 on Windows 10, latest packages)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%I` instead of `%H`, as noted in [this bug report](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/341). This was not documented, so I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/pull/560) adding a note about it to the documentation.